# How to configure Google AppEngine to work with vector graphic?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, svg, java-8, awt

In AppEngine standard environment with Java8 during attempt to use SVG next error appears. I get this error when I try to draw SVG on a XSLFSlide with POI like `slide.draw(graphics2D)` or to convert SVG to PNG with Batik.
The problem seems to appear because fontconfig cannot find fonts. In debian distribution it solves by installing `libfontconfig1`. How to solve it on AppEngine?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:774)
at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:443)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:491)
at java.awt.Font.canDisplay(Font.java:1980)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextParagraph.canDisplayUpTo(DrawTextParagraph.java:756)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextParagraph.getAttributedString(DrawTextParagraph.java:640)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextParagraph.breakText(DrawTextParagraph.java:248)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextShape.drawParagraphs(DrawTextShape.java:159)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextShape.getTextHeight(DrawTextShape.java:220)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawTextShape.drawContent(DrawTextShape.java:102)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawSimpleShape.draw(DrawSimpleShape.java:93)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawSheet.draw(DrawSheet.java:71)
at org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawSlide.draw(DrawSlide.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.draw(XSLFSlide.java:307)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've faced the same problem and managed to solve it by explicitly telling the AppEngine VM a specific font configuration to pick up, by setting the `"sun.awt.fontconfig"` system property. Try inserting the following code somewhere at the very beginning of your source code (before using any font or graphic components):

```
    String fontConfig = System.getProperty("java.home")
            + File.separator + "lib"
            + File.separator + "fontconfig.Prodimage.properties";
    if (new File(fontConfig).exists())
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.fontconfig", fontConfig);
```

Comment: Fixed it for me, Thank you!